# Interfaces and inheritance with derived class

Tags: c#, linq, inheritance, interface, polymorphism

I am stuck on interfaces and inheritance. If I implement two classes who both have an interface each, how would I be able to add the properties of Class A and B together? For instance I wanted to associate `firstitem` with the `seconditem`.

```
public interface IAlpha
{
  [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "/AddBravoToAlpha/{firstitem}/{seconditem}")]
  void AddBravoToAlpha(int firstitem, int seconditem);
}
public interface IBravo
{
    // what goes in here?
}
public Class Alpha
{
    public Alpha()
    {
        AlphaAdd = new List<Bravo>();
    }
   int Firstitem { get; set }
   public List<Bravo> AlphaAdd { get; set; }
}
public Class Bravo 
{
   public Bravo() 
   {
        BravoAdd = new List<Alpha>(); //not sure if Bravo can access Alpha (derived class)
   }
   int Seconditem { get; set }
   Guid Indexer { get; set }
   public List<Alpha> BravoAdd { get; set; }
}
public Class BravoDoesAlpha : IBravo, IAlpha //????
{
    List<Alpha> alpha = new List<Alpha>();
    List<Bravo> bravo = new List<Bravo>();

    public void AddBravoToAlpha(int firstitem, int seconditem)
    {
        var result = alpha.Where(n => String.Equals(n.Firstitem, firstitem)).FirstOrDefault();
        var result1 = bravo.Where(n => String.Equals(n.Seconditem, seconditem)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (result != null)
        {
            result.BravoAdd.Add(new Alpha() { Firstitem = firstitem });
        }
        if (result1 != null)
        {
            result1.AlphaAdd.Add(new Bravo() { Seconditem = seconditem });
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If `Class A` already implements `Interface A` why do you need to implement it again in `Class B`? And you could always just try to create this scenario.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because _very little of the code would actually compile_

Comment: Why do you think separating class `A` and `B` into separate `.cs` files means you need a third derived class? If `A` and `B` share some common methods which describe what they do, then you could create a single interface to cover that functionality (say it's called `IDoStuff`), of which *both* `A` and `B` implement:

`public class A : IDoStuff {}` and `public class B : IDoStuff {}`

Feeding through odd bits of information here and there isn't going to help you get an accurate answer in a timely manner as the goal posts keep moving.

Comment: @KirstyWhite based on your comments to this and my answer, I think you need to go back to the drawing board and think about how this site can help. The idea of SO is to answer narrow questions that have objective answers. It is impossible to read your mind or the mind of whomever is asking you to do these things. It started as a question about interfaces and inheritance in pseudo-code and the latest update is that you need to make a web service? It is all achievable but only if you have a clear idea of what you need to do first.

Comment: Apologies, the code should look alot clearer now. However I am not sure what I should put in the interface for Bravo? As I said I was asked to implement an interface for both Alpha and Bravo. However I keep coming back to just the one interface.

Comment: @KirstyWhite no need to apologize, just keep narrowing question. It still isn't narrow enough, but I gave you a general answer in return for a general question. The question I saw was "how do I do an interface extraction" and I gave an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so the question you are being asked is basically one about how to do a certain kind of refactoring known as "extracting" an interface.

This is one of the more easy refactorings to do and to understand if you understand interfaces vs. types.

All interfaces are types, but not all types are interfaces.

Now let's assume we are dealing in a world with two families of types: classes and interfaces (as in your example).

Instead of working your example directly, I will work a different but clearer example that does not use `Alpha`, `Bravo`, `Charlie`, `Epsilon`, etc. because this kind of stuff makes it harder to see the meaning.

First, here's the before:

```
public class Dog
{
    public void Bark() { Console.WriteLine("Woof!"); }

    public int NumberOfDogLegs { get { return 2; } }

    public int NumberOfDogFriends { get; set; } // this can be set

    private string SecretsOfDog { get; set; } // this is private
}

public class DoorBell
{
    public void Chime() { Console.WriteLine("Ding!"); }
}
```

To extract the interface of a class, simply, well, *extract* all the public members of the class to an interface.

```
public interface IDog
{
     void Bark();
     int NumberOfDogLegs { get; }
     int NumberOfDogFriends { get; set; }
}

public interface IDoorBell
{
     void Chime();
}
```

Now to really make use of OOP, you can find a way to abstract `IDog` and `IDoorBell`. What do they have in common? Well, the obvious one is they both make a noise. So we make a new interface, `public interface IMakeANoise` and say that `IDog` and `IDoorBell` both implement it.

```
public interface IMakeANoise
{
     void MakeNoise();
}

public interface IDog : IMakeANoise
{
     void Bark();
     int NumberOfDogLegs { get; }
     int NumberOfDogFriends { get; set; }
}

public interface IDoorBell : IMakeANoise
{
     void Chime();
}
```

And now we have a new method to implement on `Dog` and `DoorBell`.

```
public class Dog : IDog
{
    public void Bark() { Console.WriteLine("Woof!"); }

    public int NumberOfDogLegs { get { return 2; } }

    public int NumberOfDogFriends { get; set; } // this can be set

    private string SecretsOfDog { get; set; } // this is private

    public void IMakeANoise() { Bark(); }
}

public class DoorBell : IDoorBell
{
    public void Chime() { Console.WriteLine("Ding!"); }

    public void IMakeANoise() { Chime(); }
}
```

Now let's say we are actually writing a video game and `Dog` and `DoorBell` are both things that we can show on the screen. Well, this makes them a lot bigger because we will need to provide more information like their coordinates, their states, etc.

In this case, `Dog` and `DoorBell` may be very different to us but are similar enough to potentially merit sharing a base class. (Really, this is a stretch, but it does get the point across.)

Without adding all those new interfaces and their implementations, let's just do the "sharing a base class" refactoring for what we already have.

```
public class RenderableThing : IMakeANoise, IDoAThousandOtherThings
{
    protected virtual string MyNoiseToMake { get { return ""; } }

    public virtual void MakeANoise()
    {
         Console.WriteLine(MyNoiseToMake);
    }
}

public class Dog : RenderableThing, IDog
{
    protected override string MyNoiseToMake { get { return "Woof!"; } }

    public void Bark() { MakeANoise(); } // see what we did there?

    // Notice that I am not declaring the method MakeANoise because it is inherited and I am using it by overriding MyNoiseToMake

    public int NumberOfDogLegs { get { return 2; } }

    public int NumberOfDogFriends { get; set; } // this can be set

    private string SecretsOfDog { get; set; } // this is private   
}

public class DoorBell : RenderableThing, IDoorBell
{
    public void Chime() { Console.WriteLine("Ding!"); }

    public override void MakeANoise()
    {
         Chime(); Chime(); Chime(); //I'll do it my own way!
    }
}
```

You may wonder, what's the point? So we can do this...

```
IMakeANoise dogNoiseMaker = new Dog();

IMakeANoise doorBellNoiseMaker = new DoorBell();

IList<IMakeANoise> listOfNoiseMakers = new List<IMakeANoise>();
listOfNoiseMakers.Add(dogNoiseMaker);
listOfNoiseMakers.Add(doorBellNoiseMaker);

foreach (IMakeANoise noiseMaker in listOfNoiseMakers)
{
    noiseMaker.MakeANoise();
}

// This will output

// Woof!
// Ding!
// Ding!
// Ding!
```

Comment: I did what you asked but **please please please don't actually use this code** , it is not how you implement what you want to do, I was only trying to do what you asked

Comment: @KirstyWhite it is simply the wrong name. I will just delete that and keep the second attempt at filling in the blanks, but I'll do a third attempt that kind of keeps only the spirit of your question without the code.

Comment: When you mentioned web services, I was thinking something like what [this](http://www.codemag.com/article/0809101) discusses; composing a web service by implementing multiple interfaces, that would result in something like [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xK6SGW). But then with the latest updates, I'm still no closer to understanding what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Shouldn't `Dog` now implement `IDog`?

Comment: @DanielFlint I think that KirstyWhite has more than one question at a time but maybe feels like the best place to start is with inheritance? We don't have enough information to begin to guess I feel

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a shot in the dark and venture a guess that you don't quite understand what interfaces and inheritance is. I'll start off by explaining what interfaces are:

**Interfaces** contain only the definitions of methods, properties, events or indexers that an inheriting class must implement.

For example:

```
interface IExample
{
    void HelloWorld();
}

class ExampleClass : IExample
{
    public void HelloWorld()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world.");
    }
}
```

Now for **Inheritance**; when you derive a class from a base class the derived class will inherit all members of the base class except for the constructors. Note: Depending on the accessibility of the members in the base class it's children may or may not be able to access the parents members.

```
public class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Animal(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public void Talk()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is talking", Name);
    }
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    public Cat(string name) : base(name) { }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public string FurColor { get; set; }

    public Dog(string name, string furColor) : base(name)
    {
        FurColor = furColor;
    }

    public void Greeting()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} has {1} fur.", Name, FurColor);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cat = new Cat("Rex");
        cat.Talk();

        var dog = new Dog("Beanie", "Red");
        dog.Talk();
    }
}
```

Comment: The more examples the better and good that you included something runnable.

Comment: Thanks! Just thought i'd add my 2 cents in :)